# creating a fat16 model

Tags: c++, c, delphi, pascal

i am trying  to create a Model FAT16 file system in a file with the ability to create, view, delete and copy files and directories,but i new to programming anyone with ideas on how i can go about it?i want something like this below

```
type
  TFileRec = Packed Record
    ID: WORD; //id of item
    ParID: WORD; //parent id
    Name: String[8]; //name of item
    Ext: String[3]; //extension if any (type)
    Att: BYTE; //attributes (access modifiers, type, etc)
  end;

var
  FAT16: File of TFileRec;
  ItemCount: Integer;
```

Comment: I mucked about with a "FAT64" system some time ago: http://code.google.com/p/cpfs/source/browse/#hg%2Fsrc%2Fcpfs, you might find some useful stuff in there. Also the MS spec on FAT32 contains everything you need to create a FAT16 system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at [Compound File implementation](http://gp.17slon.com/gp/gpstructuredstorage.htm) by SO user Primoz Gabrijelcic. It is not FAT16, but very close to what you are looking for.

Answer (score 2):

The way I suggest to do it is to tweak a FAT 16 implementation to use a file as the hard disk media. The interface of a FAT file system to hard disk is system level commands like read_sectors and write_sectors which read/write multiples of 512B buffers to certain LBA addresses. For your case, you can replace the calls to read sectors and write sectors functions with actual read writes to the file.

So by changing these two functions, you are replacing the media accesses with file accesses.

To be exact, there is a third system level call to the hard disk which returns the size of media, which here should be replaced with the maximum file size which suppose to act as media.

a light weight FAT implementation can be found at [here](https://ccrma.stanford.edu/courses/250a/docs/avrlib/html/fat_8c-source.html)